For compact objects, should the diagram be categories, posets or ordinals?
In the nlab, a compact object $X$ is defined as one such that $\text{hom}(X,-)$ preserves $k$-filtered colimits for some $k$, i.e. diagrams from some $k$-filtered category $D$. But then, in that same page they asume that $D$ is in fact a poset. Meanwhile, my book (Hovey) takes $D$ to be an ordinal. Do all these notions coincide?
Coinciding here could mean (e.g., for the first and last case), from strongest to weakest:

Any diagram from a filtered category is equivalent to one from an ordinal. I.e. there is an isomorphism between the set of cocones.
If $C$ has all ordinal colimits then it has all filtered colimits.
If $C$ has both colimits, $\text{hom}(X,-)$ preserving $k$-ordinal colimits implies it preserves $k$-filtered colimits.


Relevant: "every filtered category admits a final functor from a directed set" https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2940401

Nice! That only leaves comparing the case of ordinals and filtered categories/posets.

One thing to note: Hovey's book on model categories is interested in "compact objects" for the purposes of Quillen's small object argument. For this, you only need an object (specifically the domains in the generating set of cofibrations) to be compact relative to transfinite compositions (i.e. indexed by an sufficiently filtered ordinal) of a certain form. This is considerably weaker than hom(X,-) preserving (sufficiently) filtered colimits, but it's enough for the purpose of SOA.

A good reference where these questions are answered is: Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories by J. Adamek and J. Rosický. The numbering below will refer to that book. Also note that in that book, and more commonly nowadays, the term $\kappa$-presentable is used for what the linked nLab page calls $\kappa$-compact.
As already mentioned in the comments: every (small) $\kappa$-filtered category $\mathcal{D}$ admits a cofinal functor $H: \mathcal{D}_0 \to \mathcal{D}$ from some $\kappa$-directed poset $\mathcal{D}_0$. This is Remark 1.21.
In that same Remark 1.21 it is also mentioned that we cannot generally replace $\kappa$-filtered categories by ordinals. Generally, this only works when $\kappa = \omega$. This makes the exact formulation of your second point true, because when $\kappa = \omega$ we leave it out of the notation. So a filtered colimit is an $\omega$-filtered colimit, etc. More precisely:

For any regular $\kappa > \omega$ there is a poset with joins (i.e., colimits) of chains of cofinality $\geq \kappa$, but with a $\kappa$-directed set that has no upper bound (and thus no colimit). This is exercise 1.c(3).
Again, let $\kappa > \omega$ be regular. If $\operatorname{Hom}(X, -)$ preserves colimits of chains of cofinality $\kappa$ it need not preserve $\kappa$-directed colimits, even in a cocomplete category. This is exercise 1.c(4), which is stated for $\kappa = \omega_1$, but I believe it works for general $\kappa$ as well. The exercise also does not state anything about cocompleteness (only having $\omega_1$-directed colimits), but when following the hint you get a cocomplete category.
For $\kappa = \omega$ it all simplifies. The precise statement can be found as Corollary 1.7, which I will repeat here. A category has directed colimits iff it has colimits of chains. For such categories $\mathcal{K}$, a functor $F: \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{L}$ preserves directed colimits iff it preserves colimits of chains. So the first part tells us that having colimits of chains (i.e., of ordinal diagrams) is the same as having directed/filtered colimits. The second part tells us that to check if an object is finitely presentable (i.e., $\omega$-compact) it is enough to check that its hom-functor preserves of colimits of chains.

The final point comes with a warning. It does not say that any directed poset contains a cofinal chain. I am not entirely sure how to interpret the first bullet point in your question, but this seems false. A counterexample is given in Example 1.8: consider $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ as a category. The directed poset of finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ does not admit a cofinal chain. The point is that we can build any directed colimit from colimits of chains, but we may need to repeat taking colimits to get there.
